# Linux - Accessing mmap()ed memory from Thread from Userspace in Kernel Space

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kgdb

Mapped this memory in my Thread in Userspace:

```
b7fd0000-b7fd1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
```

Thread is running (endless loop)

Made a breakpoint in the Kernel and trying to access it:

```
Thread 466 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 3908]
0xc10d4060 in kgdb_breakpoint ()
(gdb) x/01i 0xb7fd0000
   0xb7fd0000:  Cannot access memory at address 0xb7fd0000
```

But it is not accessible.

How can I access 0xb7fd0000 from Kernel space? What address will be under?

Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The address the memory will appear under depends on which user space context is currently mapped.

The way this works is, some of the virtual addresses are reserved to the kernel, and these are the same in all contexts. This is why you can set a break point on a kernel address without worrying about which user space process is currently mapped.

For user space, this is not the case. Each time a new process is mapped, the virtual addresses for US change completely.

This is, likely, an X-Y problem. You're trying to do something, and you *think* that a kernel level break point is how you want to achieve it.

Taking a guess, you want your kernel driver to do something to communicate with your user space thread. If that's the case, your best bet is to export a character device, and have the userspace open it and mmap from there (rather than just an anonymous mmap). You can then control which memory it receives, and thus also map it to the kernel address space, where pointers are stable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in kgdb but it will be worth checking `current->pid` at the time breakpoint is hit, contains pid of the process you're tracking. This is because although memory location inside kernel space has been hit, the user space process may not be the one you are interested in. Also to guard against possibility of pages being swapped out, it might be safer to lock mapped pages using `mlock`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things to pay attention to.

1. `When to break`. If you simply hit crtl-C in the kernel debugger, you don't know what the userspace context is going to be. It could be any userspace process. You want the kernel debugger to pause and give you control when the userspace context refers to the process you are interested in. One way to do this is as follows :- If you have the ability to recompile the kernel, add a new system call. Invoke this system call from the userspace process, after the region is mmap'd in. Start debugging the kernel after placing a breakpoint on the newly added system call. When the breakpoint is hit, you know for a fact that the userspace context is that of the process one you are interested in.
2. `Virtual memory late binding`. Even if you follow the steps in [1], you will still have trouble when accessing the contents of the buffer in userspace, if you have not read / written anything in that location. Make sure that after mmap'ing the region, you either read or write to the mmap'd location before invoking your newly added system call.